# Python, Tensorflow import non dataset images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pyqt5

I am working on my school project about machine learning with python. I have created a linear classifier with tensorflow and have learned the MNIST dataset with over 90% accuracy.

Predicting the dataset testing data works fine, but the problem is when I want to import data that are not from the testing dataset (maybe just an image created in paint).

I have created a simple GUI for my presentation and it worked fine with it too, but just not with for example .png image.

I have tried something with Pillow, but looks like it doesn't work well.

Can you please help me ? I will accept any advice. Thanks a lot.

Here is the tensorflow code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
learn = tf.contrib.learn
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

global i, test_labels
i = 0


def display(i):
   img = test_data[i]
   plt.title('Example %d, label %d' % (i, test_labels[i]))
   plt.imshow(img.reshape((28, 28)), cmap=plt.cm.gray_r)
   plt.show()


global mnist
mnist = learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
test_data = mnist.test.images
test_labels = np.array(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)


def train_me(max_examples, batch, step):

   data = mnist.train.images
   labels = np.array(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)

   data = data[:max_examples]
   labels = labels[:max_examples]

   feature_columns = learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(data)
   cls = learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,    n_classes=10)
   cls.fit(data, labels, batch_size=batch, steps=step)

   return cls


def test_me(cls):

   im = Image.open("dva-test.png")

   global prediction
   prediction = cls.predict(im, as_iterable=False)
```

Here is the GUI code:

```
import sys
import digits as dig

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QToolTip,  QPushButton, QMessageBox, QDesktopWidget, QMainWindow,
                         QLabel, QAction, QFileDialog)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Gui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.setFixedSize(500, 200)
        self.center()
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Not trained')

        exAct = QAction('Exit', self)
        exAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exAct.triggered.connect(self.close)

        impAct = QAction('Import picture', self)
        impAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+I')
        impAct.triggered.connect(self.file_import)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(impAct)
        fileMenu.addAction(exAct)

        trainBtn = QPushButton('Train', self)
        trainBtn.resize(trainBtn.sizeHint())
        trainBtn.move(155, 120)
        trainBtn.clicked.connect(self.trainning)

        testBtn = QPushButton('Test', self)
        testBtn.resize(trainBtn.sizeHint())
        testBtn.move(255, 120)
        testBtn.clicked.connect(self.testing)

        text = QLabel("Please import file and train the classifier before testing.", self)
        text.resize(text.sizeHint())
        text.move(120, 40)

        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle('Digits')

        self.show()

    def trainning(self):
        global classifier
        classifier = dig.train_me(10000, 100, 1000)

        classifier.evaluate(dig.test_data, dig.test_labels)
    self.statusBar().showMessage('Accuracy: ' +
                                 str(classifier.evaluate(dig.test_data,        dig.test_labels)['accuracy']))

    def testing(self):
        dig.i = 2
        dig.test_me(classifier)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Predicted %d, label: %d" % (dig.prediction, dig.test_labels[dig.i]))

    def file_import(self):
            name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Import File')
            print(name)

    def closeEvent(self, event):

        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message', "Are you sure you want to exit ?",
                                 QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def center(self):

        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Gui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Rather than post your entire code can you post the error your are getting and only the relevant part of the code? Reading through large code blocks for some generic error that isn't specified is hard and not as likely to get an answer as a more specific, focused question.

Comment: It's hard to say, because what happens, it's just python breaks and left no error. Debugger found error in tensorflow module, but I think that's not the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

Tensorflow will accept only 1D arrays, and my image was 3D, array. shape = [28, 28, 3]. So I have removed the RGB dimension and ravel the 2D array.

The result of this I have imported to Tensorflow classifier, but I realized I need to invert the colors, so every zero in the array should equal to 1 and every 1 to zero.

Here is the code:

```
    im = mpimg.imread('dva-test.png')
    im = im[:, :, 0]
    im = im.ravel()
    for j in range(len(im)):
        if im[j] == 0:
            im[j] = 1
        elif im[j] == 1:
            im[j] = 0

     global prediction
     prediction = cls.predict(np.array([im], dtype=float), as_iterable=False)
```